# Why does Hydra SMB attack not work while Metasploit does?

Tags: password-cracking, brute-force, metasploit, hydra

I'm learning about password attacks, and doing TryHackMe labs.

- User: penny
- Pass: leo1234

When using Hydra to find the password for the SMB user, I get no valid results:
[image]

I know the valid password is present in the wordlist, and the dictionary attack works with metasploit:
[image]

Can anybody explain to me the reason for this?

Commands used:

Metasploit:

```
auxiliary/scanner/smb/smb_login
set passfile [wordlist]
set smbuser penny
set rhosts [target ip]
```

Hydra:

```
hydra -l penny -P [worlist] [target ip] smb
```

Comment: Hi @UndercoverDog I just added them to the post.

Comment: Please copy/paste text and use the code formatting tool rather than entering images because images are so difficult to read.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make sure you weren't mixing up targets,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - Hydra defaults to NTLM dialect but in your use case it requires LMv2.

```
Hydra v8.6 (c) 2017 by van Hauser/THC - Please do not use in military or secret service organizations, or for illegal purposes.

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2023-03-27 16:21:56
[DATA] max 1 task per 1 server, overall 1 task, 222 login tries (l:1/p:222), ~222 tries per task
[DATA] attacking smb://10.10.179.28:445/Local LMV2
[....]
[ATTEMPT] target 10.10.179.28 - login "penny" - pass "leo1234" - 63 of 222 [child 0] (0/0)
[445][smb] host: 10.10.179.28   login: penny   password: leo1234
1 of 1 target successfully completed, 1 valid password found
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) finished at 2023-03-27 16:21:57
```

According to the source code for the Hydra `smb` module:

> The "-m 'METHOD'" option is required for this module. The
> following are valid methods: Local, Domain, Hash, Machine,
> NTLMV2, NTLM, LMV2, LM (in quotes).
> Local == Check local account.
> Domain == Check credentials against this hosts primary
> domain controller via this host.
> Hash == Use a NTLM hash rather than a password.
> Machine == Use the Machine's NetBIOS name as the password.
> NTLMV2, NTLM, LMV2, LM == set the dialect

In the source there is also a `usage_smb` that states:

> Module smb default value is set to test both local and domain account, using a simple password with NTLM dialect.  Note: you can set the group type using LOCAL or DOMAIN keyword or other_domain:{value} to specify a trusted domain.  you can set the password type using HASH or MACHINE keyword (to use the Machine's NetBIOS name as the password).  you can set the dialect using NTLMV2, NTLM, LMV2, LM keyword.
> Example:
> hydra smb://microsoft.com  -l admin -p tooeasy -m "local lmv2"
> hydra smb://microsoft.com  -l admin -p D5731CFC6C2A069C21FD0D49CAEBC9EA:2126EE7712D37E265FD63F2C84D2B13D::: -m "local hash"
> hydra smb://microsoft.com  -l admin -p tooeasy -m "other_domain:SECONDDOMAIN"

**References**
[hydra-smb.c](https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/blob/d6a42ace44cd39a5dd7c534fa863d972513569b4/hydra-smb.c)

Comment: Thank you for the great help!